# CSS issue with UL > LI > LI

Tags: css, html-lists, wordpress-theming

On a website I'm trying to complete, I'm having some trouble getting the CSS right for the main navigation menu.

When a menu item has child pages, the drop-down for those is supposed to be a solid colour with no border, but have round corners on the bottom and also have a drop shadow.

I've got it mostly right, but the middle link (LI) is getting the same round corners as the last LI and I cannot figure out why.

I've also noticed that my menu's LI hovers are not getting the round corners where they're supposed to be.

The site is http://landtrecruitment.com.au.

Thanks

Comment: You might want to change `.menu ul > li + li` to `.menu ul > li:last-child` for a start. Then we can see where we are.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

try this

```
.menu ul > li + li{
    border: 0 solid #333333;
    border-radius: 0 0 10px 10px;
    box-shadow: 0 5px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
```

**please add + li in this above css**

```
.menu ul > li + li + li{
    border: 0 solid #333333;
    border-radius: 0 0 10px 10px;
    box-shadow: 0 5px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
```

OR

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_nth-last-child

```
 .menu ul  li:nth-last-child(1)

    {
      border: 0 solid #333333;
            border-radius: 0 0 10px 10px;
            box-shadow: 0 5px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);}
```

Comment: the `.menu ul > li:nth-last-child(1)` was the fix.  Thanks!

Comment: and adding `:nth-last-child(1)` to the 2nd li in `.menu li li a:hover` fixed the issue I had with the bottom corners of the hover for that last one too.   I sorted the left corners on hover issue I had for the home menu option by taking out the `a:hover` from `.menu > li:first-child`.

Comment: I note you mention nth-last-child won't work in IE8 and below... will your `ul > li + li + li` ??  How would that go with more than three menu options - would I have to add a 4th and 5th +li?

Comment: please try this css ie8 working /* equivalent to li:nth-last-child(1) */
.menu ul  li:last-child

    {
      border: 0 solid #333333;
            border-radius: 0 0 10px 10px;
            box-shadow: 0 5px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);}

Comment: may i sure try this IE7 OR IE8 working /* equivalent to li:nth-child(4) */
.menu ul > > li:first-child + li + li + li {
 border: 0 solid #333333;
            border-radius: 0 0 10px 10px;
            box-shadow: 0 5px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

Comment: /* equivalent to li:nth-child(5) */  add + li + li + li + li{ your css }  /* equivalent to li:nth-child(6) */  add + li + li + li + li + li{ your css }

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32870/discussion-between-falguni-and-reece-dodds)